# How can I get the DateTime for the start of the week from Monday instead of Sunday

Tags: c#, datetime

How to display the current week start date and end date from Monday to Sunday instead of Sunday to Saturday. The following code gives Sunday to Saturday

```
DateTime baseDate = DateTime.Today;
var today = baseDate;
var yesterday = baseDate.AddDays(-1);
var thisWeekStart = baseDate.AddDays(-(int)baseDate.DayOfWeek);
var thisWeekEnd = thisWeekStart.AddDays(7).AddSeconds(-1);
```

This gives 21 May 2023 to 27 May 2023 where I need it to be  22 May 2023 to 28 May 2023

Comment: I don't feel none of the answers meet my requirement